# Celery restart causes redelivery of scheduled tasks in RabbitMQ

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a celery worker which consumes tasks from a RabbitMQ broker. This works great until a restart of the worker. `celery multi restart -A proj` causes all the scheduled(Unacked) messages to become ready again which then immediately starts getting redelivered causing a delay in consumption of new incoming tasks depending on the number of the scheduled tasks.

The speed of redelivery depends on the concurrency of the workers.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You can try purging the queue.

Comment: Won't that cause loss of scheduled tasks?

Comment: True that. Can you try and create a simple worker that receives and acks tasks selectively?

Comment: Hello from 2023, have you found a solution?